# How to prove that if the centripetal acceleration is $\frac{v^2}{r}$ then the path of motion is a circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

From all the resources I checked in internet or textbooks,it is pretty clear that in a uniform circular motion, the centripetal acceleration is $\frac{v^2}{r}$. However, I found it hard to prove the statement reversely. How do we prove that if the centripetal acceleration is $\frac{v^2}{r}$, then the path of motion is a circle with radius r given that initial v is not zero. In other words, if centripetal acceleration is greater than $\frac{v^2}{r}$, the particle will spiral inwards, if centripetal acceleration is less than $\frac{v^2}{r}$, the particle will spiral outwards.

Comment: "How do we prove that if the centripetal acceleration is v2r, then the path of motion **is a circle with radius r**." [Emphasis added.] It's not. For example if the initial velocity is zero, the path is a line.

Comment: There is no reverse form of that statement. When the motion is along a circle with radius $r$, with uniform velocity $v$, then the corresponding centripetal acceleration is $\tfrac{v^2}{r}$. A context where reversing is meaningful does exist though. Treat the case in terms of exerted *force*. Force causes acceleration. You can have insufficient force to sustain a particular configuration, or a surplus of force, or just enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does an acceleration always perpendicular to velocity imply a circular motion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/595120/)

Comment: @Cleonis Force does not **cause** acceleration. Force **implies** acceleration. It is not the same thing.

Comment: @JohnRennie Although the question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/595120/does-an-acceleration-always-perpendicular-to-velocity-imply-a-circular-motion?noredirect=1&lq=1 contains some element to answer this question it is not a duplicate. Here, there is no hypothesis of ${\bf a}\cdot {\bf v}=0 $.

Comment: @GiorgioP although Jack does not say so explicitly the question only makes sense if a and v are normal so the condition a.v = 0 is implied. If Jack edits the question to say this is not the case I will reopen the question.

Comment: @GiorgioP You write: "Force does not cause acceleration. Force implies acceleration." Can you elaborate? Example: an object is accelerated with a [slingshot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slingshot) I think of the process of the elastic bands contracting as exerting a force, causing acceleration of the object.  Contact information for me is available on my stackexchange profile page. Must proceed via email; stackexchange comment is not for discussion, I endorse that SE policy. I give my word that if you email me with explanation I will take time to read and understand.

Comment: @GiorgioP For the time being I'm reading the answer you posted on Aug. 20, 2021

Comment: @JohnRennie In no place in the question I can see something that may imply a.v=0.